# How to force CURRENT directory permissions on all sub-directories in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, permissions

I'm often finding myself in a situation where I login to shell as root (I've already been told it's a bad practice) and copy new files to some directory served by apache.

Since I'm logged in as root, the new files will have root set as owner, and different permissions than the files which are already present, and I'll need to change the permissions for Apache to be able to access the files. I am doing it manually.

I am researching a better way of doing it. I was wondering if there is a way to somehow apply with a single command the permissions of the current folder to all it's sub-folders and files.

Windows has such a feature, where you can "reset all files and folder permissions" to those of the parent folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the permissions on the current directory, you can use

```
stat -c %a .
```

To set permissions recursively, use

```
chomd -R
```

Put together, it gives

```
chmod -R `stat -c %a .` .
```

Or, you can use the `--reference` option of `chmod` if supported.

```
chmod -R --reference=. .
```

Comment: Worked like a charm:

    `chmod -R --reference=. .`
    `chown -R --reference=. .`

Answer (score 1):

+1'd @choroba's answer but... are you sure that's what you want to do?

*From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions ...*

> **Permissions**
>   Unix-like systems implement three specific permissions that apply to each class:
>
> - The read permission grants the ability to read a file. ***When set for a directory,
>     this permission grants the ability to read the names of files in the directory,
>     but not to find out any further information about them such as contents, file type,
>     size, ownership, permissions.***
> - The write permission grants the ability to modify a file. ***When set for a directory,
>     this permission grants the ability to modify entries in the directory. This includes
>     creating files, deleting files, and renaming files.***
> - The execute permission grants the ability to execute a file. This permission must
>     be set for executable programs, including shell scripts, in order to allow the operating
>     system to run them. ***When set for a directory, this permission grants the ability to access
>     file contents and meta-information if its name is known, but not list files inside the
>     directory, unless read is set also.***
>
> The effect of setting the permissions on a directory, rather than a
>   file, is "one of the most frequently misunderstood file permission
>   issues".
>
> When a permission is not set, the corresponding rights are denied.
>   Unlike ACL-based systems, permissions on Unix-like systems are not
>   inherited. Files created within a directory do not necessarily have
>   the same permissions as that directory.
>
> ***(emphasis added)***

Comment: Thank you. I have discovered since (this post is years old) that Linux has an ACL facility, at least on Debian. (acl, setfacl, chacl, etc.). I understand that they are inheritable. But these ACLs are somewhat of a secondary, optional feature. I found out about ACLs by being faced with a variant of the problem that I described in the initial post above. But this time, instead of resetting the permissions, I added additional ACLs.